# Is there a way to get bass from pyaudio data?

Tags: python, audio

sorry if this does not make sense, basically I have a bunch of data flowing into a list with 1024 elements. What I want to do is extract the low frequency ones out of them, however I do not know exactly how this pyaudio thing works.

What I have:

```
    wf = wave.open('song.wav', 'rb')
    p = pyaudio.PyAudio()
    stream = p.open(format=p.get_format_from_width(wf.getsampwidth()),
                    channels=wf.getnchannels(),
                    rate=wf.getframerate(),
                    output=True)

    data = wf.readframes(CHUNK)
    while len(data) > 0:
        stream.write(data)
        data = wf.readframes(CHUNK)
        decoded = numpy.frombuffer(data, dtype=numpy.int16)
        print(decoded)

    while len(data) > 0:
        stream.write(data)
        data = wf.readframes(CHUNK)
        decoded = numpy.frombuffer(data, dtype=numpy.int16)
        print(decoded)
```

Currently the output looks like this:

```
[  53  225 -496 ... 2328  384 2363]
[ 597 2091  757 ... -235 -146 -304]
[  190  -146   478 ... -1574  2376 -2444]
[ 2100 -3066  1491 ...  -939  -174  -127]
[ -353   736  -258 ... -1723  -707 -1836]
[-1257 -2033 -1548 ... -2535  3562 -2650]
[ 1807 -2672   131 ...   382  3786 -1292]
[ 4523 -2838  4932 ...  2692 -1329  3022]
```

What I am looking for is the low frequency bits, again I am not sure how this exactly works so I would like to request from an expert!

Comment: To get frequencies, you have to transform your wav signal (Time domain) to the spectrum (Frequency domain) with FFT (Fast Fourier Transform). To do that, you can use `Numpy` or probably the simplest is to use [`librosa`](https://librosa.org/doc/0.8.0/generated/librosa.stft.html)

Comment: Will look into it, thanks for the information!